# Rails remote form not verifying authenticity token

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

In ruby on rails 6, I submit the following form:

```
<%= form_with url: "/subscribe_newsletter", local: false, id: "newsletter-form" do |f| %>
        <%= f.email_field :email, placeholder: "Entrez votre courriel...", required: true %>
        <%= f.hidden_field :conversion_source, value: "newsletter-block" %>
        <%= f.submit "S'inscrire", class: "cta", "data-action" => "click->abonnement#busyCursor" %>
    <% end %>
```

Here is the controller action:

```
class AccountController < ApplicationController
    layout 'blank'

    def subscribe_newsletter 
        user_params = {
            email: params[:email],
            conversion_source: params[:conversion_source] ||= ""
        }
        # we create an account and send confirmation
        new_user = User.new(user_params)
        new_user.skip_password_validation = true
        if new_user.save
            flash[:notice] = "Inscription réussie ! Vérifiez vos courriels pour confirmer votre inscription."

            respond_to do |format|
                format.js
            end
        end
    end
end
```

The issue is Rails is not checking the authenticity token. If I manually modify the authenticity token in the hidden field or even delete it, the User is still created.

Any idea why Rails is not verifying the authenticity token for this form submission? Thanks.

SOLUTION:
Apparently the form takes the authenticity token from the meta tag in the head section. It makes sense as it's a remote form.

Comment: Do you have `protect_from_forgery` in your `ApplicationController`?

Comment: No, I tried to add it but it didn't change anything. But actually, my bad, I was modifying the authenticity_token in the hidden field of the form, but not in the meta tag in the head section. Apparently the form takes the authenticity token from there since it's a remote form. Makes sense!

Comment: Indeed, you also need the `csrf_meta_tags` in the head, that would have been the next thing to check.